# Set DeserializeObject in anonymous property of a class

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have this:

```
    public class ComponentData
    {
        public dynamic CdHtml { get; set; }
        public dynamic CdJson { get; set; }
        public dynamic CdSection { get; set; }
        public dynamic CdContainer { get; set; }
        public dynamic CdRow { get; set; }
        public dynamic CdContainerId { get; set; }
        public dynamic CdColsJson { get; set; }
    }
```

And i want to set the ComponentData Class with these values but i get an error:

```
            var componentData = new ComponentData()
            {

                CdHtml = obj.htmlCD,
                CdJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(obj.jsonCD),
                CdContainerId = "SECTION" + obj.CD_Container_Id,
                CdSection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(pc.Build_CDxxxJson("xxx" + obj.CD_Container_Id, "width:" + tlj.width.ToString() + "%;padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:30px;" + sectionCenterStyle, "section")),
                CdContainer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(pc.Build_CDxxxJson("xxx" + obj.divGUID2, containerStyle, "container")),
                CdRow = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(pc.Build_CDxxxJson("xxx" + obj.divGUID3, "", "row")),
                CdColsJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(pc.Build_CDxxxJson(obj.divGUID4, "", string.Format("col-xs-{0} col-sm-{1} col-md-{2} col-lg-{3} hoversel colregion{4}", bsc.xs, bsc.sm, bsc.md, bsc.lg, obj.divGUID4), bsc.xs, bsc.sm, bsc.md, bsc.lg))
            };



            return Json(new { componentData = componentData, html = obj.html });
```

how would i return this class with the json objects inside and pass it back to the client using ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
var componentData = new ComponentData()
{

  CdHtml = obj.htmlCD,
  CdJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(obj.jsonCD),
  CdContainerId = "SECTION" + obj.CD_Container_Id,
  CdSection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(pc.Build_CDxxxJson("xxx" + obj.CD_Container_Id, "width:" + tlj.width.ToString() + "%;padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:30px;" + sectionCenterStyle, "section")),
  CdContainer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(pc.Build_CDxxxJson("xxx" + obj.divGUID2, containerStyle, "container")),
  CdRow = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(pc.Build_CDxxxJson("xxx" + obj.divGUID3, "", "row")),
  CdColsJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(pc.Build_CDxxxJson(obj.divGUID4, "", string.Format("col-xs-{0} col-sm-{1} col-md-{2} col-lg-{3} hoversel colregion{4}", bsc.xs, bsc.sm, bsc.md, bsc.lg, obj.divGUID4), bsc.xs, bsc.sm, bsc.md, bsc.lg))
};
```

If you want to convert to dynamic you need to use `ExpandoObject` just as you would use when you want to create one with your hands.